# Understanding an MLP coefficient array

Tags: machine-learning, python, neural-network, scikit-learn

I have implemented a super simple MLP using SKLearn. I have a 2 hidden layer model and 31 features on the input layer. So the lengths of the arays are 31, 20 and 10.

```
print(len(mlp.coefs_[0]))
print(len(mlp.coefs_[1]))
print(len(mlp.coefs_[2]))
```

When I inspect `mlp.coefs_[0]`, it shows 20 objects in each nested list. So I guess, it's one weight assigned to each of the 20 nodes in layer 2.

```
array([[ 0.04831248, -0.03457129, -0.06804578, -0.06056679, -0.02949333,
        -0.00956451, -0.11401471, -0.11448489,  0.01421299, -0.01884066,
        -0.13625769, -0.17885363, -0.12397866, -0.16187424, -0.04780782,
        -0.18715104,  0.06372367, -0.00276321, -0.11435387, -0.13513219],
```

How do I know which feature this relates to? And why would the same feature have different weights in different nodes?

Comment: why wouldnt the same feature have different weight in different node since different nodes are connected differently in relation to other nodes?

Comment: `mlp.coefs_[0]` are the weights of the 1st hidden layer per input feature, 20 of them, one for each 1st layer node , right?